# JPA2 Criteria : Many to Many Join Table, how to do the restriction on the Join table

Tags: jpa, query-optimization, criteria, join

I've a very basic Many to Many relationship between 2 entities.

Let say Car :

```
public class Car {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "CAR_GARAGE",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID", nullable = false) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "GARAGE_ID", nullable = false) })
    private List<Garage> listGarages;
}
```

And Garage :

```
public class Garage {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "CAR_GARAGE",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "GARAGE_ID", nullable = false) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID", nullable = false) })
    private List<Car> listCars;
}
```

I need to do a query to retrieve all the CAR from one garage:

```
public Long getCarFromGarage(final String pGarageId) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Car> crit = builder.createQuery(Car.class);

    // jointure
    Root<Car> root = crit.from(Car.class);
    Join<TarifEntiteFac, Garage> garageJoin = root.join("listGarages");

    crit.where(builder.equal(garageJoin.get("id"), pIdentifiant));

    return em.createQuery(crit).getResultList();
}
```

This works fine but the SQL generated is something like this :

```
SELECT c.id 
FROM CAR c 
INNER JOIN CAR_GARAGE cg ON c.id = cg.CAR_ID
INNER JOIN GARAGE g on cg.GARAGE_ID = g.ID
WHERE g.ID = :pGarageId
```

Is there a way in JPA to generate this instead :

```
 SELECT c.id 
    FROM CAR c 
    INNER JOIN CAR_GARAGE cg ON c.id = cg.CAR_ID
    INNER JOIN GARAGE g on cg.GARAGE_ID = g.ID
    WHERE cg.GARAGE_ID = :pGarageId
```

To save myself an extra join.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a way how to force only single join with many-to-many relationship, unless there is some query hint or provider specific option that turns this optimization on.

However, you may generate single join also by mapping the intermediary table as an entity and adding additional onetomany mapping to this entity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my question was without remapping the join table to an entity, cheers.